# How to disassemble Renesas RX210 MCU firmware?

Tags: firmware-analysis

I am a beginner in firmware reverse engineering. I have a dump file of Renesas RX210 MCU firmware but, I don't know how to disassemble it. Is any recommended software to disassemble it?

Comment: IDA pro seems to have Renesas RX support since ver 7.7 https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/news/7_7/#new-processors

Comment: It depends. When you look at the firmware in a hex editor, does it have an ELF header? If so, you may be able to use the rx-elf-objdump tool in the GNU cross-compiler suite.

Comment: No, it doesn't have any ELF header

Comment: @Robert, Thanks for your tip, but how to identify the entrypoint of this file on ida

Comment: The on-chip program ROM lives at the end of the 32-bit address space and the reset vector address is found in the last 4 bytes of this (i.e. @ 0xFFFFFFFC.)  If you are lucky you might find that the firmware file is effectively a program ROM image and you can find the address accordingly.

Comment: @lan Cook Thanks a lot for useful tip